# WMI Error in event log every boot: EventID 5605

Tags: windows-event-log, wmi

I have a few servers that I keep getting the [EventID error 5605](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727103%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> The root\cimv2\TerminalServices namespace is marked with the
>   RequiresEncryption flag. Access to this namespace might be denied if
>   the script or application does not have the appropriate authentication
>   level. Change the authentication level to Pkt_Privacy and run the
>   script or application again.

The issue is I have no clue where this script is being run from so I can't update the script to solve the issue like every other post I have found on Event 5605. I checked the GPO for startup scripts, I checked all of my domain's SYSVOL share for a VBScript or Powershell script. I can't find this script anywhere. How can I track down this script and fix it so it stops throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WMI Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826686(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Event Viewer, this will allow you to link WMI queries to a specific process.

1. Open Event Viewer.
2. On the View menu, click Show Analytic and Debug
   Logs.
3. Locate the Trace channel log for WMI under Applications and
   Service Logs | Microsoft | Windows | WMI Activity.
4. Right-click the Trace log and select Log Properties.
5. Click the Enable Logging check box to start the WMI event tracing.

WMI events appear in the event window for WMI-Activity.

This event log is sometimes painful to use, so you can use a script like this to start tracing and view events, with process name attached to the WMI queries:

```
$wmiLog = "Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Trace"
echo y | Wevtutil.exe sl $wmiLog /e:true
Read-Host -Prompt "Tracing WMI Started. Press [ENTER] to stop"
echo y | Wevtutil.exe sl $wmiLog /e:false
$events = Get-WinEvent -LogName $wmiLog -Oldest | Where-Object {$_.message.Contains("Operation = Start") -or $_.message.Contains("Operation = Provider") }

if ($events -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "No WMI events in trace!"
    return
}

$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Computer")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Namespace")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Type")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Query")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("UserName")
[void]$table.Columns.Add("Process")

ForEach ($event in $events)
{
    switch ($event.Properties.Count)
    {
        6 {
            $typeStart = $event.Properties[1].Value.IndexOf("::")+2
            $typeEnd = $event.Properties[1].Value.IndexOf(" ",$typeStart) 
            $type = $event.Properties[1].Value.Substring($typestart,$typeEnd-$typeStart)
            $query = $event.Properties[1].Value.Substring($event.Properties[1].Value.IndexOf(":",$typeEnd)+2)
            $process = Get-Process -Id ($event.Properties[2].Value) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($process -eq $null) 
            { 
                $process = "($($event.Properties[2].Value))"
            }
            else
            {
                $process = "$($process.Name) ($($process.Id))"
            }      

            [void]$table.Rows.Add(`
                $env:COMPUTERNAME,`
                "\\.\root\cimv2",`
                $type,`
                $query,`
                "N/A",
                $process)
        }
        8 {
            $typeStart = $event.Properties[3].Value.IndexOf("::")+2
            $typeEnd = $event.Properties[3].Value.IndexOf(" ",$typeStart) 
            $type = $event.Properties[3].Value.Substring($typestart,$typeEnd-$typeStart)
            $query = $event.Properties[3].Value.Substring($event.Properties[3].Value.IndexOf(":",$typeEnd)+2)
            $process = Get-Process -Id ($event.Properties[6].Value) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($process -eq $null) 
            { 
                $process = "($($event.Properties[6].Value))"
            }
            else
            {
                $process = "$($process.Name) ($($process.Id))"
            }

            [void]$table.Rows.Add(`
                $event.Properties[4].Value,`
                $event.Properties[7].Value,`
                $type,`
                $query,`
                $event.Properties[5].Value,
                $process)
        }
        default
        {
            Write-Error "Unexpected number of event properties."
            Write-Host $event
            Write-Host $event.Properties
        }
    }
}

$table | Out-GridView
```

Tracelog.exe and tracefmt.exe from [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=96667) can also be used for WMI tracing.

Answer (score 0):

As this is WMI it often reflects a remote call. For example Lansweeper scanners trigger this error but for different namespace: root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftTPM. You might need to monitor the network traffic coming to the affected server so that you identify the source of the WMI query if it's not anything local.

Comment: The question is **three** years old. Just sayin'.